# mvnw confusing error message NoPluginFoundForPrefixException

Tags: maven

Why does:

```
./mvnw -X versions:set -DnewVersion=${VERSION_TO_DEPLOY}
```

Give this error:

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'C' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\tools\mvnrepo), nexus (https://nexus.corporate.net/repository/maven-public/)]
```

Maven points to the [error documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException)

But that does not help much either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of some tracing (set -x in mvnw) it appears that mvnw uses the environment variable $MAVEN_CONFIG on our build server which happens to be used by other software as well for different purposes.

Thanks to [this bug report](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47890) it starts to make sense

If this happens to point a local Windows file (without -config in front of it) maven will try to resolve it as a plugin:

C:\tools\apache-maven-2.2.1\conf\settings.xml